# Creating a matrix in python alternating between 1s and 0s

Tags: python, list, loops, matrix

For a 3 by 3 matrix, how can I create a matrix that has values which alternate between 1s and 0s?

```
table = [ [ 0 for i in range(3) ] for j in range(3) ]
for row in table:
    for d1 in range(3):
        for d2 in range(3):  
            table[d1][d2]
    print row
```

Above is edited text of the code I used to create a 3 by 3 matrix with zeros, however, I want something like this

```
1 0 1
0 1 0 
1 0 1
```

A 3 by 3 matrix that alternates between 1 and zero question beforehand. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Yes, of course there is, but **what have you tried and what exactly is the problem with it?** Note that you can combine `i` and `j` to determine whether each digit should be `0` or `1`.

Comment: Use `(i + j + 1) % 2` instead of `0`.

Comment: Peter Wood, could you please explain why (i+j+1)%2 gets 1 0 1? I don't understand why the 2nd 1 becomes 1, as I have no allocated the values, wouldn't that mean it would be 0+0+1% which is 0.5.

Comment: @Mad_Questionnaire % is the modulo operator => 0 % 2 = 0, 1 % 2 = 1, 2 % 2 = 0, ...

Comment: Oh, @JulienSpronck, it seems I've been wrong with what modulo operator does, I simply thought it divides it by, in this case, 2 and gives the answer back.

Comment: @Mad_Questionnaire, it is the remainder of the division by 2.

Comment: @Mad_Questionnaire are you trying to delete the question? why?

Answer (score 2):

You could slice and reshape.

```
import numpy as np
n = 3
a = np.zeros(n*n, dtype=int)
a[::2]=1
a = a.reshape(n, n)
```

If you prefer not using numpy, Peter Wood's suggestion is nice and compact.

Answer (score 1):

`values` is an iterator that yields 0 and 1 forever:

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> values = cycle([0, 1])
>>> [[next(values) for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
[[0, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0]]
```

It works well when the number of columns is odd, not when it's even:

```
>>> values = cycle([0, 1])
>>> [[next(values) for i in range(5)] for j in range(4)]
[[0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]]

>>> values = cycle([0, 1])
>>> [[next(values) for i in range(4)] for j in range(5)]
[[0, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using `numpy`:

```
flat_list = [1-i%2 for i in xrange(9)]
print [flat_list[i:i+3] for i in xrange(0,9,3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function to create a nxm 1 0 matrix. If you want to start with 0 1 sequence, consider to modify the code block a litte.

```
import numpy as np
def my_one_zero_matrix(n,m):
    zeros_a=np.zeros((n,m))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            if (i+j)%2==0:
                zeros_a[i,j]=1
    return zeros_a
```